# Data retreived by ID from NodeJS server showing NULL in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am using axios to make api calls using a proxy server with nodeJS as backend and reactJS as frontend.

```js
node js file

const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios').default;
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/api')
})


// get anime on front page
app.get(`/api`, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime');
        const data = response.data
        res.json(data.data)
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
})


// get anime by id
app.get('/api/anime/:id' ,async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const id = req.params.id
        const response = await axios.get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/${id}`)
        const data = response.data
        res.json(data);
        console.log(data)
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('connected')
})
```

Here I am using Two routes, one for the main homepage to show all the data, and then one route to retrieve data by ID, but when i try to retrieve the data using ID it shows null in console.

```js
import useFetch from "./usefetch";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import './style/animeDetails.css'


const AnimeDetails = () => {

    const play = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target)
    }
    const {id} = useParams()
    const { data: animeDet, isLoading, error } = useFetch('/api/anime/' + id);
    console.log(animeDet.data)
    return ( 
        <div className="details">
           
    
       </div>
     );
}
 
export default AnimeDetails;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here i am making a call to the proxy server to retrieve the data by ID.

Comment: Can you post the `useFetch` function?

Answer (score 0):

try to check isLoading first, like:

```
  const { data: animeDet, isLoading, error } = useFetch('/api/anime/' + id);
    

  if (isLoading) {
    return null
  }

  console.log(animeDet.data)

  return ( 
        <div className="details">
           
    
       </div>
     );
```